# Spring data duplicate key value after CrudRepository.save method call

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on my personal project, and there I observe a strange behaviour in spring `CrudRepository.save`. There is a unique constraint in one of the field. When I save a new record with a duplicate value for this field, I didn't get any exception until the request handler method completes. Is this a normal behaviour?
DB is Postgres

```java
RuleSet save = ruleSetRepository.save(convertToRuleSet(request));
fileRepository.createRuleSet(request);
try {
   gitRepository.commitAddPush(request.getRuleSetName(), "Added rule set " + request.getRuleSetName(), gitVersion);
} catch (GenericGitException gitException) {
   fileRepository.deleteClassDirectory(request.getRuleSetName());
   fileRepository.deleteRuleSet(request.getRuleSetName());
   throw new CommonRuleCreateException(gitException.getMessage());
}
return new RuleSetResponse(save.getId(), save.getName(), save.getDescription(),save.getPackageName());
```

This entire method get called without any exception.

Answer (score 2):

What you might be missing is that `save` method will commit to DB after transaction is completed, generally end of method execution. If you want to save to DB at that time only, use `saveAndFlush`.

Also if you want, you can make sure that your repo methods are using a new transactions and not same as that of its caller methods. So that when repo method call is completed, it will save transaction data into DB.